# Database algorithm Simple Nested Loop Join

Tags: database, algorithm

Given Relation:

```
Sailors (sid: integer, sname: string, rating: integer, age: real)
Reserves (sid: integer, bid: integer, day: dates, rname: string)
```

Query

```
SELECT  *
FROM   Reserves R, Sailors S
WHERE  R.sid=S.sid
```

Assume:

```
M pages of R, pR tuples per page (i.e., number of tuples of R = M * pR) 
N pages of S, pS tuples per page (i.e., number of tuples of S = N * pS)
```

Cost is the number of I/Os (ignore the output cost)

Algorithm for the query

```
foreach tuple r in R do
    foreach tuple s in S do
        if ri == sj  then add <r, s> to result
```

Cost

```
Scan of outer  +    for each tuple of outer, scan of inner relation.

Cost  =     M    +     pR * M * N  I/Os
```

I am confused with the final result for the cost. If we were to scan every tuple in R and then for each r, scan every tuple in S then wouldn't the final cost be `R*S = M*pR*N*pS` ? (R = M * pR , S = N * pS). I'm not sure why there is an addition symbol. Does I/O only account for pages? and not records?

Answer (score 2):

You are giving yourself the right answer:

> Does I/O only account for pages? and not records?

The cost in these cases is calculated in numbers of *disk accesses*. An I/O operation transfers an entire page, not a record, from disk to main memory and vice-versa (this is exactly the meaning of a page: the minimum unit of transfer between the two memories).

So, since the Nested Loop algorithm reads the relation `R` only once, the first term is equal to the number of I/O operations to read it, which is equal to the number of its pages.

Comment: If it read only pages, then shouldn't the cost be M*N (where M is the number of Pages for Reserves and N is the number of Pages for Sailors)

Comment: No, since for *each* record of `R` (that is `M * pR`), the algorithm reads *all* the pages of `S` (that is, `N`). Note that the situation is asymmetric, so that the cost changes if you excange the role of `R` and `S`.